# Accessing union members with the union name without any variables

Tags: c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    union {
    int id_num;
    char VIN[20]; 
  } id;

    id.id_num = 20;
    printf("%d",id.id_num);
    }
```

why is the above code working when the id union's id_num member is being accessed with the union's name (id.) and not a declared id union  variable?
I'm very confused

Comment: `id` is a variable and the type of `id` is the unnamed union. If you want to give the union a name, put it between the `union` and the `{`.

Comment: But `id` _is_ the name of the variable. The union _type_ doesn't have a name.

Comment: I did not know that,Thank You

Comment: Sometimes it helps to remember that the notation for declaring a `union` is the same as for declaring a `struct` (and a `class` if we include `C++`).

Answer (score 4):

The [union type declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union) is

`union` *`OptionalUnionTypeName`* `{` `...` `}`

but your full statement is a variable definition of the form

`type` `id` `;`

(where type is the anonymous union type just declared, since you omitted the name).

So `id` is a variable of (anonymous) union type.

Comment: This is of course absolutely correct. It could be noted (because it may lead to confusion similar to the OP) that a `union` type may also be named via a `typedef` as in `typedef union { ... } <TypeName>;`.